# Copy Column between tables replicates first cell in target rather than copying column

Tags: excel, vba

I'm copying a column of formulas between 2 tables of similar size and format.  I can copy values between tables with no problem, but if I try to copy formulas, and there is a formula in the first row of the source data, that formula gets replicated to the whole target column and the rest of the source data is ignored.  Works fine if there are other formulas in source as long as none is in the first row.

I've tried turning off autofill with

```
Application.AutoCorrect.AutoFillFormulasInLists = False (doesn't work)
```

Also tried using:

```
SrcTable.DataBodyRange.Columns(1).Copy DestTable.DataBodyRange.Columns(1)
```

but it results in absolute table column references so if a source formula referred to a column in its own table, it would refer back to that column rather than a column of the same name in the new table (doesn't work for my case).

```
DestTable.DataBodyRange.Columns(1).Formula = _
SrcTable.DataBodyRange.Columns(1).Formula
```

The above code works as I need it to, as long as a formula isn't in the first row of the source column.  Anyone know how to make it work in that use case without having to copy the first row separately to avoid the inexplicable replication problem?